# Check if there are records in the past 24h

Tags: php, mysql, date

My problem is simple : I have a button that must be displayed if there are some records in the past 24h in the database. I explain :

I have a table in my db that contains Datetime (day/month/years hours:minutes:seconds like 15/01/2015 21:14:05). I want every records to be stored in a `<table>` in another page named `Warning` if I click on the button. My problem is that the button must be displayed on the first page ONLY IF there are records between the last 24h and now. I want something like that :

```
if (isset(records in the past 24 hours))
{
   echo "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"location.href='../Warning/Warning.php';\" value=\"WARNING\"/>";
}
```

I tried using `date("d/m/Y h:m:s", time() - 60 * 60 * 24)` but I think I don't use it correctly.
How to check if there are records in the past 24h ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the records like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM records WHERE datetimefield >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c106f/1/0

In PHP you can do the same thing like this:

```
$recInLast24 = array()
foreach($records as $record) {
  if(strtotime($record['datetimefield']) >= time() - 24 * 60 * 60) {
    $recInLast24[] = $record;
  }
}
if(count($recInLast24) > 0) {
  echo "<button...";
}
```

There are more possible ways.

Comment: It seems correct but idk why `SELECT count(*) FROM records WHERE datetimefield >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);` return 0... I just added a new record for today so it should return 1. I'm trying to figure it out

Comment: paste your INSERT statement and i will have a look on it.

Comment: I tried `mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db,"SELECT count(*) FROM alerte WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Date_heure, 'd%/m%/Y% H%:i%:s%') >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);"));` in case if the date is string but doesn't work either

Comment: but you stored the datetime in a datetime field and not in a varchar field right ?

Comment: The query in phpmyadmin return 0 too

Comment: It works with a new records 17/06/2015 19:05:14. Idk why